# Is it possible for a css file to stop working after I npm install some things?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

so I have been starting out with React and built a website, with bootstrap too, now there is this contact form that I want to make work, therefor I am using express and nodejs to do so.
The website was working, I created a separate folder "server" which stores the server.js file and the package.json
However, after I installed and created this file, I ran it and the css stopped working. I did not change anything in my app.js or css file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navigation from './components/navigation';
import Header from './components/header';
import Features from './components/features';
import About from './components/about';
import Services from './components/services';
import Gallery from './components/gallery';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import JsonData from './data/data.json';

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    landingPageData: {},
  }
  getlandingPageData() {
    this.setState({landingPageData : JsonData})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getlandingPageData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Header data={this.state.landingPageData.Header} />
        <Features data={this.state.landingPageData.Features} />
        <About data={this.state.landingPageData.About} />
        <Services data={this.state.landingPageData.Services} />
        <Gallery />
        <Contact data={this.state.landingPageData.Contact} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my css:

```
body, html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
    color: #252525;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ddd;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
h5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 20px;
}
p {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
p.intro {
    margin: 12px 0 0;
    line-height: 24px;
}
a {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-weight: 400;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff0000;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
}
ul, ol {
    padding: 0;
}
hr {
    height: 2px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 0;
}
/* Navigation */
#menu {
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
#menu.navbar-default {
    background-color: #252525;
    border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)
}
#menu a.navbar-brand h2{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}



#menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 20px 2px;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 9px 20px 0 20px;
}
#menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    content: "";
    transition: width 0.2s;
}
#menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:after, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover:after, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus:after {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    bottom: -1px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 2px !important;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 100%) !important;
    content: "" !important;
    transition: width 0.2s !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #252525;
    border-color: #ff0000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover>.icon-bar {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.section-title {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.section-title h2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.section-title h2::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4e4e 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -30px;
    left: 50%;
}
.section-title p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.btn-custom {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4e4e 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    padding: 14px 34px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    border: 0;
}
.btn-custom:hover, .btn-custom:focus, .btn-custom.focus, .btn-custom:active, .btn-custom.active {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.btn:active, .btn.active {
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
a:focus, .btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn.active.focus {
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: none;
}
/* Header Section */
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.intro .overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.intro h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 82px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.intro h1 span {
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #ff0000;
}
.intro p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
header .intro-text {
    padding-top: 350px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Features Section */
#features {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #252525;
}
#features i.fa {
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6372ff 0%, #5ca9fb 100%);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}


/* About Section */
#about {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-color: #252525;
}
#about h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
#about h2 {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#about h2::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4e4e 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#about .about-text li {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
#about .about-text li:before {
    content: '\f00c';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
#about img {
    width: 520px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
}
#about p {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
/* Services Section */
#services {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #252525 0%, #252525 100%);
    color: #252525;
}
#services .service-desc {
    margin: 10px 10px 20px;
}
#services h2 {
    color: #fff;
}
#services .section-title h2::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #ff0000;
    height: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -30px;
    left: 50%;
}
#services i.fa {
    font-size: 42px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #6372ff 0%, #5ca9fb 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
#services h3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
#services p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
#services .service-desc {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
/* Portfolio Section */
#portfolio {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-color: #252525;
}
.portfolio-item {
    margin: 1px -15px 0 -14px;
    padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-item .hover-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
.hover-bg .hover-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4e4e 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    padding: 30% 0 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.hover-bg .hover-text>h4 {
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hover-bg:hover .hover-text>h4 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.hover-bg:hover .hover-text {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Testimonials Section */
#testimonials {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
#testimonials i {
    color: #e6e6e6;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.testimonial {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
.testimonial-image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.testimonial-image, .testimonial-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.testimonial-content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.testimonial-content p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.testimonial-meta {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #666;
}
/* Team Section */
#team {
    padding: 100px 0;
}
#team h4 {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#team .team-img {
    width: 240px;
}
#team .thumbnail {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
#team .thumbnail .caption {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    color: #888;
}
/* Contact Section */
#contact {
    padding: 100px 0 60px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4e4e 0%, #ff4e4e 100%);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
#contact .section-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#contact .section-title p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#contact h2 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#contact .section-title h2::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    height: 4px;
    width: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30px;
}
#contact h3 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#contact form {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#contact .text-danger {
    color: #cc0033;
    text-align: left;
}
#contact .btn-custom {
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
#contact .btn-custom:hover {
    color: #1f386e;
    background: #fff;
}
label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
}
#contact .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
#contact .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #999;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: transparent;
    box-shadow: transparent;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #777;
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
color: #777;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
color: #777;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #777;
}
#contact .contact-item {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
#contact .contact-item span {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}
#contact .contact-item i.fa {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#contact .social {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
#contact .social ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#contact .social i.fa {
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#contact .social i.fa:hover {
    color: #608dfd;
    background: #fff;
}
/* Footer Section*/
#footer {
    background: #ff4e4e;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
#footer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#footer a {
    color: #d3d3d3;
}
#footer a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #608dfd;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
#about img {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

#menu a.navbar-brand h2{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #menu a.navbar-brand h2{
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #ffffff;
        margin-top: -1vh;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #e3e3e3;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 20px 2px;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: 9px 20px 0 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #menu a.navbar-brand h2{
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 1vh;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #e3e3e3;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 20px 2px;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: 9px 20px 0 20px;
    }
}
```

Btw, app.js is inside the src folder and the style.css is inside the public folder.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `The css stopped working`... what does that mean? Did you get a 404 error on loading the css file? Or did the selectors not work? You also don't seem to show us where you load your css file...

Comment: I could see the whole website, meaning html and css would load, the images/text would be display and styled, but not anymore. 
I didn't change anything on those files

Comment: Can you check your inspector network tab to see if a file is not loading now? And include the part of your code where you load your css

Comment: I just checked and the CSS is being loaded, however, I don't know where I am loading it.
 It used to work...

Comment: We can't really help you if we don't know what's wrong. The css is loaded but not applied? Have you inspected the components that don't get css and see if classes have changed or something else that broke your css selectors? This question in its current form isn't answerable by anyone right now

Comment: Yes from my understanding, the css is loaded but not applied. I checked on the network manager and it is being loaded, I see the style.css there. But the page isn't being styled.
None of the components are getting css, I only added the node.js and server. 
What would you need to see, in order to be able to find out what's wrong?

Comment: There are more questions before we can help you. Did you use create-react-app? What are you using in your backend to serve the website? Are you seeing the issue when you go to the dev build of react or static build from your server?

Comment: Hey, yes I used creat-react-app name of my app, I am using node js for a contact form I have, to send me an email with the users message and email. Could you please elaborate on the dev build? I apologize I am new to react